# An installing error about castro

Tags: python, installation

castro information:
Castro is a library for recording automated screencasts via a simple API.

link:https://pypi.python.org/pypi/castro/1.0.6

I've already installed the vnc server and then "easy_install castro",  finally error occurs as followed, i googled it but there are few information about castro.

So, if you ever encountered it, pls tell the solution, thanks!

error:

---

> WARNING, No "Setup" File Exists, Running "config.py"
>
> Using WINDOWS configuration...
>
> Path for SDL not found.
>
> Too bad that is a requirement! Hand-fix the "Setup"
>
> Path for FONT not found.
>
> Path for IMAGE not found.
>
> Path for MIXER not found.
>
> Path for SMPEG not found.
>
> Path for PNG not found.
>
> Path for JPEG not found.
>
> Path for PORTMIDI not found.
>
> Path for COPYLIB_tiff not found.
>
> Path for COPYLIB_z not found.
>
> Path for COPYLIB_vorbis not found.
>
> Path for COPYLIB_ogg not found.
>
> If you get compiler errors during install, doublecheck
>
> the compiler flags in the "Setup" file.
>
> Continuing With "setup.py"
>
> WARNING, DLL for smpeg library not found.
>
> WARNING, DLL for tiff library not found.
>
> WARNING, DLL for SDL_ttf library not found.
>
> WARNING, DLL for SDL_image library not found.
>
> WARNING, DLL for vorbisfile library not found.
>
> WARNING, DLL for jpeg library not found.
>
> WARNING, DLL for vorbis library not found.
>
> WARNING, DLL for SDL_mixer library not found.
>
> WARNING, DLL for png library not found.
>
> WARNING, DLL for SDL library not found.
>
> WARNING, DLL for ogg library not found.
>
> WARNING, DLL for z library not found.
>
> WARNING, DLL for portmidi library not found.
>
> warning: no files found matching 'readme.txt'
>
> no previously-included directories found matching '*\CVS'
>
> no previously-included directories found matching '**\CVS'
>
> error: Setup script exited with error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat

---

Answer (score 1):

1. Manual install Win32 .msi package.
2. Downlaod from http://www.pygame.org/download.shtml  ->pygame
3. downlaod from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyYAML   ->yaml
4. install the .msi package.
5. try

   $ python -c "import castro; castro.test()"